# Windows 10 - Unhook "tel://" association

Tags: windows-10, file-association

When I click a link starting with tel: Windows automatically opens Skype. Does anyone know a way to force it to open the app selector dialog again? To be clear, I don't want to just associate a different app. I want to be prompted to select an app when I click the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Open *Registry Editor*.
2. Goto `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\callto\shell\open\command`.
3. Delete the Key Value.
4. Do the same to `HKEY_CURRENT_USERS\Software\Classes\callto\shell\open\command`.
5. Goto `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\tel` and remove the value of Key `ProgId`.
6. Restart Computer.

Edit: Included one more key.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the settings at Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Default Programs -> Set Associations (Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program).

Comment: As I said, I don't want to associate a different program and that menu has no option to set "none" as the association.