# Trouble with default app registrations in Win10

Tags: file-association, skype-for-business

I have used the info in this post [Can't change tel protocol handler in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1112229/cant-change-tel-protocol-handler-in-windows-10/1118456#1118456)

The results have been good on the registry side, but the tel: and callto: hyperlinks still try to open Skype (Lync) or ask for a program instead of launching my company UC client even though the registry open/command points to the exe of my UC client.  **I need help figuring out what else is causing it to launch Skype instead of my UC client?**

Registry changes in place are:
Key (CALLTO): HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\callto\shell\open\command
Value: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Company UC\Communicator.exe" "%1"

Key (TEL): HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\tel\shell\open\command
Value: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Company UC\Communicator.exe" "%1"

Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync
new DWORD (32-bit) Value named “DisabledProtocolHandlerRegistrations”
Set the Value of this new entry to “3” which is the hex sum of 1(tel:) and 2(callto:)

All of the above values stick after reboot; even after logging into Skype, however, when clicking on a hyperlink for either tel: or callto: it still tries to launch Skype

Comment: Does the default windows setting not work because you need to pass parameters?

Comment: @Confuzing Not sure exactly what you are asking.  The only parameter I would be passing is the destination phone number.  But I am not even getting that far; I can't even get the correct program to launch.  When I try to change the default program using the control panel it only lets me select Skype or the App Store, which won't work

Comment: The control panel was what I was asking, I guess if the program is not recognized to handle the protocol it doesn't show up in the list. I would guess then that Set Defaults By App also doesn't show callto and tel as options for your program? Also you probably want to update your question if you have already tried all the default program settings.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to re-set those values in the Skype for Consumer (=SfC) client? Open it and disable the options, then restart the SfC client and re-enable it (to ensure they are written to the registry). This can be done in the advanced options, here is an example:

[image]

If that didn´t work do the following:

1.) In Control Panel go to Default Programs and then Set Default Programs (the quickest way is to hit the Windows key and type “Default Programs“).

2.) Scroll down to Skype (desktop) or Skype for Business (to fix both!), then click on chose defaults for this program.

[image]

3.) Select or deselect the options here depending on your needs.

[image]

***P.S. Please make sure that SfB and SfC are up to date, to avoid that there is a bug somewhere which prevents you to change that this way. If you are unsure if the clients are up to date get in contact with your local IT.***

Comment: Thanks, Bastian.  This looks like it should work but security has locked down some of these controls so I am unable to change them even though I am a local admin on my machine.  I have opened a ticket with my IT Support to continue working on the issue.  THanks for your input!