# Can't change tel protocol handler in Windows 10 1909

Tags: windows-10, protocol-handler

I would like to add a local application to the list of potential protocol handlers for TEL that is presented in the system settings. The accepted solution of [Can't change tel protocol handler in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1112229/cant-change-tel-protocol-handler-in-windows-10#) does not work for me. May be because of changes to Windows 10 in the last years?

Comment: The accepted solution to that question absolutely should still work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not for me. I used the suggested registry sript, replaced only the name of the command, ran the script, and restarted the computer. But there was no additional option "Dialer" for the CALLTO and TEL protocols.

Comment: Being confronted with the same issue (accepted answer in linked thread doesn't work anymore in build 1909) I found a blog where a citrix consultant coded a nice little tool to change the File Type Associations per User: https://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/10/25/setuserfta-userchoice-hash-defeated-set-file-type-associations-per-user/ - I verified it to work on Win 10 1909.

Comment: Could it be that the application to be added to the list of choices must "known" to Windows in some way other than just being in a directory on the PATH?